# redirect tomcat to apache in local system

Tags: spring, apache, spring-mvc, tomcat, xampp

I am running a spring MVC project on apache tomcat with 8080 port at http://localhost:8080/project_name/

my dependencies are in apache system which is running on 80 port, for this case I need to run this URL as http://localhost:80/project_name/

I am using XAMPP for apache

> Note: Tomcat should run on 8080 port only

I have tried adding VirtualHost in `httpd.conf` file

```
<VirtualHost *:80/project_name/> 
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyRequests Off
  ServerName http://localhost/
  ServerAlias http://localhost/
  ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/project_name/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/project_name/
</VirtualHost>
```

but it is redirecting as 
http://localhost/project_name/project_name/project_name/project_name/project_name/project_name/project_name/project_name/project_name/project_name/project_name/project_name/project_name/project_name/project_name/project_name/project_name/project_name/project_name/project_name/

and showing error as below[image]

can someone help?

any solution is appreciatable

Thanks

Comment: Your VirtualHost setup should only be `<VirtualHost *:80>`.

Comment: I just replace VirtualHost as you mention but it is redirecting as http://localhost/project_name/project_name/project_name/project_name/project_name/project_name/project_name/project_name/project_name/project_name/project_name/project_name/project_name/project_name/project_name/project_name/project_name/project_name/project_name/project_name/

Comment: @Nic3500 can you send some brief solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName localhost
  ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
</VirtualHost>
```

This works fine I can access `http://localhost:8080/project_name` as `http://localhost/project_name` but I can't able to access resources( ex:`http://localhost/resources/images/header-logo-mini.jpg`) throgh apache server

Finally, I got the solution by reading this [documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html)

My solution is

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName localhost
  ProxyPass /project_name/ http://localhost:8080/project_name/
</VirtualHost>
```

Thanks @Nic3500

Thanks all